# MS SQL Query to base SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I am looking to have the following query run on any database (right now it uses `MSSQL`):

```
SELECT * FROM mytable 
WHERE 0<DATEDIFF(day, ISNULL(DateTwo, DateONE), getdate()) 
                               AND othercolumn != 'WUBAN'
```

Is there anyway to do this in a generic way?

Comment: If you attempt a generic solution with SQL, it will run equally slow on all the databases it is targeted for. It is best to use the features of a database and run separate queries that will run much faster.

Answer (score 2):

#### No, there is no generic way to do this.

If you support different DB engines you have to execute the proper SQL statement for each engine. Date functions differ on the individual DB engines and for this particular query there is no generic solution that works on all systems.

Answer (score 1):

If `DateTwo` and `DateOne` are parameters, then you are able to do the following calculation in your application:

```
DATEDIFF(day, ISNULL(DateTwo, DateONE), getdate())
```

and use the result in your query. If not, I can not see a way.

Comment: And if `dateOne` and `dateTwo` are from the DB then these values could be selected first in a generic way.